# Is there an App available for QGIS to collect data in the field - Not Roam as does not work on iPads

Tags: qgis, arcgis-collector

I would love an app which works similar to Arc's Collector App for QGIS.

On Collector App you can:

*"Collect and update data in the field, log your current location, and put the data you capture to work so you can make more informed and timely decisions. Use maps anywhere to ground-truth your data, make observations, and respond to events. You'll improve the efficiency of your field workforce and the accuracy of your GIS.
Download maps to your device and work offline.
Use GPS to create and update map data.
Collect points, lines, and area features.
Fill out easy-to-use map-driven forms.
Find places and get directions.
Track and report areas you visited."*

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143065/tablets-with-qgis-data-collection-in-the-field-image-capture

Comment: and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15957/what-ios-iphone-ipad-app-from-the-app-store-can-i-use-to-collect-data